# Using HttpClient SOAP request with MultipartContent response

Tags: c#, xml, soap, .net-core

I have a Soap HttpClient request that looks like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xop+xml"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password)));

var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = new StringContent(
        string.Format(SoapEnvelope, xml),
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/xop+xml"
    )
};
var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
var streamTask = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
```

When I write out to a file it looks like this:

> ------=_Part_1186_-1390170025.1580219662117 Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
>
> 018b838311-6ade-4699-9ab0-bfd9141e886b
>   ------=_Part_1186_-1390170025.1580219662117 Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-ID:
>   <66da1482-c934-4c83-8cac-18e64c134757@dvo.service.dcs.pi.xxxxxxxxx.com>
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> %PDF-1.3 %âãÏÓ
>
> ... //bunch of PDF stuff ....
>
> %%EOF
>
> ------=_Part_1186_-1390170025.1580219662117--

The PDF is an attachment in the response.  I'm assuming the parts of the file that have `------=_Part_1186_-139017002`   mean this is a multipart response, but from what i can see `HttpResponseMessage` does not support `ReadAsMultipartAsync()` like `HttpWebResponse` did.

Does anyone have a solution to just access the attachment from the stream?

Comment: HTTP has two modes 1) 1.0 stream mode 2) 1.1 chunk mode.  It looks like you are getting stream mode which comes in one large chunk.  I usually use             HttpWebRequest  client = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("");
            client.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; to force to stream mode

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, Im not sure I can see how chunked responses would help in this scenario. Isnt that for large responses where you dont know the length? I dont see how chunked would separate the pdf attachment from the rest of the response.